# Apply a Quota to a Kafka Connect consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have Kafka Connect JDBC sink connectors writing to various databases and I'd like to throttle the traffic to one database. The [Kafka quotas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quotas) feature can set a `consumer_byte_rate` quota for a client ID, but Kafka Connect client IDs look like `consumer-1234` and are dynamically assigned to connectors. So if my sink connector is rebalanced, it will be assigned all new client IDs. I tried setting a quota using my sink connector consumer group ID as the client ID, but that doesn't work. Is there any way to set a quota for a Kafka Connect consumer group?

Comment: What version of Apache Kafka are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to Apache Kafka 2.3 you'll benefit from [KIP-411: Make default Kafka Connect worker task client IDs distinct](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-411%3A+Make+default+Kafka+Connect+worker+task+client+IDs+distinct)
. You can see an example of it in action [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-improvements-in-apache-kafka-2-3/). However, you'd have to test if the client-id is deterministic since quotas can't be wildcarded.